# Can't run HyperV o intel Core i3-4041U

Tags: hyper-v, windows-phone-8-emulator

I can't run WP Emulator. That is my error

[image: HyperV error popup]

I am sure that I enabled hardware-assisted virtualization and disabled VT-d in BIOS. Please help me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade you OS to Windows 8/8.1 pro. You are running a simple Windows 8/8.1 version.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to enabling bios setting, you have to enable Hyper-V in Windows.

To enable Hyper-V in Windows

1.In Control Panel, click Programs, and then click Turn Windows features on or off.

2.In the Windows Features dialog box, click Hyper-V. The list of options expands.

3.In the expanded list of options, select at least the Hyper-V Platform check box, and then click OK.